# Container alignment inside a row

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I'd like to know how can i align 3 different containers inside a row so 2 of then stay on the left and 1 stay on the right.

Like this: http://prntscr.com/tovlhw.

The way i did only works for this AVD as it uses pixels to make the position.

```
 
            GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Favoritos()));
    },
                child: Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                         Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,16,0,16),
                             color: Colors.white,
                                  child: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                                                       ),

                           Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,20,140,20),
                              color: Colors.white,
                                   child: Text('Favoritos'),
                                                                        ),

                           Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(145,16,5,16),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                      child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                                                                        ),


    ],
    ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can easily be done using the `ListTile` widget with a `Card` widget(if you also want the background color):

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Favourite',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        leading: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.black),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the result
[image]

if you want to use the `Row` approach use `Spacer` like this:
also keep in mind you can use `Container` `height` property to make your row bigger.

```dart
Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.black),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10.0, // give the witdh you want between icon and text
          ),
          Text(
            'Favourite',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a row with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, to align two children evenly left and right, with the children being: 
1) A row containing the 2 items to be placed on the left
2) container contating the item to be placed on the right 
Check if this solves your problem

This works for any purpose but `ListTile` is the way to go for your case

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
height: 100px
width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child:ListTile(
leading:Icon(Icons.favorite),
  title: Text(
      'Favourite',
    ),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hy, I would suggest you wrap the Row class inside a container class and give the height and width of the container to the maximum possible. This will give the row full rectangular area and then you can align children's of row class where ever you want.

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child:  Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.08),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: RaisedButton(
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text()
              ),
             Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Submit',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:

```
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```